# Network configuration docker PHP API

Tags: php, api, docker

I'm trying to create a container with the docker API written in PHP (https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php)

I can't figure the way to configure the network using classes, if I remove the lines, container is created fine but without the port configuration :

```
    // Debug
    $name = "service_1";
    $port = 7777;


    /* Container configuration */
    $params = ["name"=>$name];

    $portConfig = new \Docker\API\Model\Port;
    $portConfig->setPrivatePort($port);
    $portConfig->setPublicPort($port);
    $portConfig->setType("udp");

    $networkConfig = new \Docker\API\Model\NetworkConfig();
    $networkConfig->setIPAddress("0.0.0.0");
    $networkConfig->setPorts($portConfig);

    $containerConfig = new \Docker\API\Model\ContainerConfig();
    $containerConfig->setImage("pyrax/samp:latest");
    $containerConfig->setNetworkSettings($networkConfig);

    /* Creation request */
    $request = $this->getDocker()->getContainerManager()->create($containerConfig, $params);
```

The "setNetworkSettings" require a NetworkingConfig object in parameter and not a NetworkConfig (i've searched in sources) and then I can't find the place to put my network config..

If someone can help :D

Answer (score 1):

```
    $hostConfig = new HostConfig();
    $portMap = new \ArrayObject();
    $portBinding = new PortBinding();

    $portBinding->setHostPort('8080');

    $portMap['80/tcp'] = [$portBinding];
    $hostConfig->setPortBindings($portMap);

    $config = new ContainerConfig();
    $config->setHostConfig(hostConfig);
```